# get statistics about postfix

Tags: postfix, logwatch

I have postfix on my server. and my server is sending about 5K emails daily i need to get some statistics about these emails in web interface (web tool) for example how many of them went to each domain (500 to @yahoo, 242 to @gmail and so on) and some other statistics. i need something other than postfix log-watch

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWStat, Demo:http://awstats.sourceforge.net/awstats.mail.html, Site:http://awstats.sourceforge.net/